# What are the best Subnet IDs for maximum number of hosts?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I need help with this problem. I know it must be either A or D since subnet mask 255.255.255.224 has the most amount of hosts. I'm confused on subnet IDs could anyone clarify why subnet ID 224 would be used?

You are the network administrator for a storage service provider. You have been tasked with configuring a number of storage servers that will be available to clients over the Internet. The configuration calls for three separate networks hosting servers that are then connected to storage systems. Because the servers will be available on the Internet, you need to assign them registered IP addresses. You contact your ISP, who assigns you a Class C address of 197.64.207.0. You want to ensure that the maximum number of host IDs are available on each network. For what value would you configure the subnet mask for the networks, and what network addresses could be used?

A. Subnet mask = 255.255.255.224, subnet IDs 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192

B. Subnet mask = 255.255.255.192, subnet IDs 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192

C. Subnet mask = 255.255.255.230, subnet  IDs 32, 64, 96, 128, 160

D. Subnet mask = 255.255.255.224, subnet  IDs 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224

Comment: Class a b c and d has not existed for like 20 years, it is all [CIDR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) now.

Comment: It *feels* as if we have a lot of Cisco homework questions these days.

Comment: note that the smaller the mask's value, the fewer bits subnetting is borrowing from the host region, so the smaller the value the more hosts (and the fewer networks.)

Comment: Another homework question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.192 lets you split it into four groups, which start with .0 and .64 and .128 and .192.  However, subnet IDs of .32 and .96 and .160 are not available when using the .192 subnet mask, so answer B is not fully correct.

.230 is not one of the common subnet mask endings of:
00000000 (0)
10000000 (128)
11000000 (192)
11100000 (224)
11110000 (240)
11111000 (248)
11111100 (252)
11111110 (254)
11111111 (255)

.230 is 11100110 so it does not have all of the 1s on the left side.  This is not commonly supported by most modern IPv4 implementations, and is therefore rejected.

.224 has subnet IDs of
.0 and .032 and .64 and .96 and .128 and .160 and .192 and .224

I would, therefore, say that answer D seems to be the most correct of those options.  (Though I would favor .192, as more groups = more addresses unavailable for host IDs.  But I cannot endorse an answer that includes clearly incorrect information, so answer B is unacceptable.)

Note that some people have historically instructed people to not use the last subnet.  I was taught that Cisco used to teach that as official recommendation, but their more recent official recommendations indicate that the last subnet is usable.  If you're using the older style of recommendations, the answer would be A.  So the preferred answer depends on what you've been taught.

It may be helpful for you to view a [VLSM Chart](http://cyberpillar.com/dirsver/1/mainsite/techns/basics/netbasic/subnet/vlsmchrt/vlsmchrt.htm).  At the bottom of the hyperlinked chart, you can see that a /27 has a subnet mask that ends with "224" (in the row showing the subnet mask's "Last 8 bits as decimal").

Comment: I'm curious what was the original reason for that recommendation. It doesn't look like it causes any problems in practice; might have been a 1980's leftover that everyone copypasted religiously?

Answer (score 2):

Think about if for a second. You are given 197.64.207.0/24.

(They call it class C but nobody has used that in several decades, barring old timers and in Cisco exams).

So you have: 197.64.207.0 with mask 255.255.255.0.
And you want to split that into at least three networks.

At least three.  You could split it in two, but that is not sufficient. The next step would be to split in four. That would yield a mask of

```
 11111111.11111111.11111111.1100000  
 255     .255.     .255    . 128 + 64
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect, `255.255.255.224` does not have the most hosts. You really need to do this in binary (ones represent network and zeros represent hosts):

```
255.255.255.224 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000
255.255.255.192 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000
255.255.255.230 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100110 - invalid (non-consecutive bits)
```

You use different subnet masks for all sorts of reasons. For example, you use `/31` or `255.255.255.254` for point-to-point links.