# Class c private address of 192.168.1.0 what subnet for most amount of host addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

Can someone help me out? I'm sure it's 255.255.255.192 since we have to make it into 3 networks. Am I correct?

You are the network administrator for a health authority in Idaho. The administration office is based in a building on the same campus as a hospital, each in its own building. Each building has its own network, connected to a backbone segment. (3 Networks)

As part of a network upgrade, you have been tasked with implementing a new IP addressing structure for the entire campus. You have chosen to use a Class C private IP address of 192.168.1.0. Now you must create separate network IDs for each network while making sure you provide as many host addresses as possible on each network. Which of the following subnet masks would you use?

255.255.255.224

255.255.255.240

255.255.255.192

225.255.255.248

Comment: Another homework question :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.192

To understand the answer, see: [TOOGAM's answer to Omar Miguel Sanane's question](http://superuser.com/a/1012943/401839).  Note that I give a different answer, because the question is *slightly* different, but the logic is the same to this question is is extremely similar (essentially identical).

Comment: could it be any other subnet mask? .192 was incorrect for some reason.

Comment: Most probable cause: this question did not match the actual homework question, because some details were left off this question.  Omar Miguel Sanane's question probably has those details.  .192 = 62 hosts, .224 = 30 hosts,.240 = 14 hosts, .248 = 6 hosts.  Since the question is asking for maximizing the number of hosts, I can say with confidence that the other potential answers are not better answers for the way that this question was written.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.0
subnetmask: 255.255.255.0

As we have to make four subnets, we need two bits, i.e., 00, 01, 10 and 11:

- 255.255.255.00000000 (1st subnet)
- 255.255.255.01000000 (2nd subnet)
- 255.255.255.10000000 (3rd subnet)
- 255.255.255.11000000 (4th subnet)

so we have four subnets, which are:

- 192.168.1.0
- 192.168.1.64
- 192.168.1.128
- 192.168.1.192

And the subnetmask for each subnet is 255.255.255.192
(hosts: 2<sup>*n*</sup>−2, where *n* is the number of bits).

For these subnets we have six bits, so 2<sup>6</sup>−2 = 62 hosts per subnet.
Broadcast addresses of the subnets:

- 255.255.255.63
- 255.255.255.127
- 255.255.255.191
- 255.255.255.255